# How do I download an app that was created with "quickly release" from "launchpad.net" to a phone?

Tags: webapps

I made a very basic app and using the command "quickly release" a file "training_16.01.9.tar.gz" on my launchpad.net page appears.

I just followed instructions like a lamb to make this happen so I don't know exactly how it works or what a .tar.gz file is. I can run this app on my Ubuntu computer with the code:

```
sudo dpkg -i ../training_16.01.9_all.deb
```

How can I make this file downloadable to work on a phone (iPhone)?